# How to change the state of only one element in a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react and I have stumbled upon a problem that I am trying to solve for several hours now but without any luck. I have an array of product sizes which I map to buttons. My goal is to change the state only of the last clicked button and to pass the value of the button to a variable. Currently whenever clicked, all buttons change their state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Button() {
  const sizes = [10, 11, 12, 13];
  const [btnState, setBtnState] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setBtnState(!btnState);

  return (
    <div className="button-component">
      {sizes.map((size, index) => (
        <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
          {size} {btnState.toString()}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wizardly-shannon-3m2kso]

Comment: `<button className="btn" onClick={() => handleClick(size)}>...</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that there is only the single state value and all the mapped buttons use the same state in the same way.

## Solution

Convert the `btnState` to an object where the `size` is a dynamic key.

```
function Button() {
  const sizes = [10, 11, 12, 13];
  const [btnState, setBtnState] = useState({});

  const handleClick = (size) => () => setBtnState(sizes => ({
    ...size,
    [size]: !sizes[size]
  }));

  return (
    <div className="button-component">
      {sizes.map((size, index) => (
        <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick(size)}>
          {size} {String(!!btnState[size])}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-change-the-state-of-only-one-element-in-a-map]

If you want only a single active state then store just the passed `size` in the callback handler in state and check it's value when mapping.

```
function Button() {
  const sizes = [10, 11, 12, 13];
  const [btnState, setBtnState] = useState();

  const handleClick = (size) => () =>
    setBtnState(size);

  return (
    <div className="button-component">
      {sizes.map((size, index) => (
        <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick(size)}>
          {size} {String(btnState === size)}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-change-the-state-of-only-one-element-in-a-map (forked)]

Comment: Thank you very much @Drew Reese .  As far as I see both solutions bring the same result that I was looking for.  I just can't quite grasp my mind into what's exactly that you did in the first one with the handleClick stacking arrow functions. It's the first time I see something like that. Even the second one isn't quite clear to me right now. Maybe I should try with a fresh mind tommorow. Thanks again..

Comment: @hanku8 Ah, yeah, they are curried functions, i.e. a function that returns a function. The first function takes an argument and closes it over in callback scope, and returns a function that is used for the event handler. It allows you to write code like `onClick={handleClick(size)}` instead of `onClick={() => handleClick(size)}`. The idea is that you immediately invoke the first function with the current iterated value, and attach the returned function as the event handler callback. It's *just* a preference of mine, but both ways are completely valid and work just fine.